# Troubleshooting for SFML set up for Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, linker, codeblocks, sfml, dynamic-linking

I have tried everything I can think of. I have followed many tutorials and experimented with trying to make SFML work on Code::Blocks. I am trying to dynamically link them.

I have gotten SFML to work on Visual Studio, but because of limited C: Drive space I want to use a smaller application. Every time I try to build it fails. I also know I need to add the .dlls to the folder the executable will be in. No matter what I try to do to fix it I always get ld.exe||can not find -SFML-xxxxx|

This error is displayed for every linker I add.

Answer (score 0):

It seems either you are using an incorrect build of SFML (with respect to the compiler) or you simply made some error while linking. The error can be because you didn't link the files in correct order (yes, order matters) or maybe something else. Your question isn't exactly very descriptive. In any case, I'd suggest check the version/build of SFML you have downloaded with the compiler you are using (it should probably be MinGW). Alternatively, you can build SFML from source using your version of the compiler.

Comment: Well I’ve tried every order and many ways of linking. And I manually installed my compiler so I know it’s the right version.